# How to disabled render on prev and next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi i'm working with fullcalendar. I need to **prevent the calendar for updating the events when clicking the next, prev or changing the view buttons**. I load or filter my events with other control (a select button). So when i moved from month to month i lost my selection done with the select button, so instead of only show me my events filtered, it shows me everything.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, I think you want to prevent the default event . If so you can you jquery  event.isDefaultPrevented() function.

Example:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope it works for you.